# Quiz database setup for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a database and I am trying to think ahead to the future with results retrieval and the time it takes to perform tasks.  Basically, I am going to have a table that hold the answers that were given on the quiz.  There are 48 questions.  Is it better to have one long row with all of the answers given and the column names after the question number.  Or should I have one row with each answer and the question ID.  Either way makes sense to me but I am pretty new at this.

Comment: There might be a few options you could consider, but option to have one long row is not one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

48 questions/columns are a lot. And what happens if you want to have only 12 or 50 questions tomorrow?

A design like

```
player_id | quiz_id | question_id | answer_id
```

will give you more flexibility in the future.